# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor '\b'

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to search a string for a specific word ('cow') using the following:

```
var regex = new RegExp('cow', '\\b');
```

I only wish to target 'cow' and not words which contain 'cow' such as 'cowboy' or 'cows' using the '\b' expression, however this results in:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor
>   '\b'

I have attempted to use 'b', '\b', '/\b' but all result in the same error.

What is the correct expression I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the regular expression special characters with the flags, it should be:

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\bcow\\b', 'g');
```

The `g` is the global flag, to search the supplied string for all matches.

References:

- [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 0):

2nd parameter for `RegExp` object is flag like `g` or `i` etc. Just use

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\bcow\\b');
```

or simply use regex delimiter:

```
var regex = /\bcow\b/;
```